# Trouble With Registerpackage On Hostgator

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I have an operational website on my development machine: Ubuntu, Apache, MySQL, Yii framework, that is working exactly the way I want it to. I am also using javascript, ajax, css and jquery for user interface purposes. I am also using Yii Bootstrap and Google Analytics.

I have moved the /protected folder out of the webroot path and have installed the Yii framework outside of the webroot path on the HostGator system.

On the hosted service, The system's basic functionality works - menu systems, maintaining basic data in the database, menu functions etc. so it appears as though the majority of the Yii framework is working properly.

I am having problems with registerPackage. In my /YiiSites/mysite/protected/config/main.php file I have the following lines to define the packages I need in the application which is identical to the configuration on my development site:

```
'clientSript' => array(
    'packages' => array(
        'doT' => array(
            'basePath'=>'application.assets'
            'js'=>array('doT.min.js'),
        ),

        'todo' => array(
            'basePath'=>'application.assets',
            'js'=>array('todo.js'),
            'css'=>array('todo.css'),
            'depends'=>array(
                'jquery',
                'doT',
            ),
        ),
        'updateWO'=> array(
            'basePath'=>'application.assets',
            'js'=>array('updateWO.js'),
            'css'=>array('todo.css'),
            'depends'=>array(
                'jquery',
                'doT',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

The view that uses these javascript files I have the following line of code:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('todo'); ?>
```

Which I would expect to create several lines of HTML code in the target containing:

`<script src="(the todo.js location)"></script><script src="(doT.js location)"> (etc.)`

The problem is that these lines of code are not showing up in the resulting HTML code. Once the HTML is rendered I do not see these lines in the resulting page source. I am using FireBug on FireFox and don't see any errors regarding this code block.

I have also noticed that the webroot/mysite/assets folder doesn't appear to have the proper .js files in a hashed subfolder (i.e., 44f87309) in the assets folder.  I have deleted all folders under webroot/mysite/assets folder and rerun the app.  Yii created 2 folders, none of which have the todo.js, doT.js or updateWO.js files in it.

Anyone have any ideas on why registerPackage is not working on the "production" configuration?

Comment: Hi, do your files 'doT.min.js', 'todo.js', 'todo.css', and 'updateWO.js' actually exist in your assets folder, because that's where you're telling Yii to look for them with the line 'basePath'=>'application.assets'

Comment: @Joe Miller - yes, they reside in (mysite)/protected/assets.

Comment: Do you still have a folder called assets under your main web root?

Comment: @Joe Miller - yes, with several subfolders named with what appear to be randomly generated 8 character strings.  None of these folders contain the necessary .js or .css files.